# How to divide a slide in beamer into two columns as shown in figure

Tags: beamer, columns

I'm wondering if someone can help me how to generate this figure using sharelatex.

[image]

Comment: For the arrows, I would use tikz.  You can put an entire itemize inside a node [text width=...].

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to show us what you already tried?

Comment: I guess people (and ducks and marmots) here would be more eager to help you if you would (a) show us what you have tried and (b) give feedback to the answers of your other questions by either saying what you think is missing or accepting them. And I agree that with @JohnKormylo that the upper part can be easily done with Ti*k*Z, and for the lower part you could either use columns or Ti*k*Z.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,bbm}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Population vs.\ sample based PCA}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-latex] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (8,1) coordinate[midway](X) -- (8,0);
\draw (X) -- ++(0,1) node[above]{PCA};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Population PCA
 \item $x\in\mathbbm{R}^m$, random vector
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Sample based PCA
 \item $\mu,\Sigma$ not known
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]